# pygame sorting list objects that are strings

Tags: python, list, pygame

I am making a game were at the start you enter your name and then it is saved as a variable. Then, you perform specific tasks and your time is counted in seconds. At the end, I want to remove the worst time, the Scoreboard to save your time if you beat a record, sort that list that contains the Scoreboard and then save it. This is my try at that, but it can't sort it in decending order since the objects in the lists are strings in order to contain the names of the players:

```
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
        b = int(end - start)
        if b < int(Scoreboard[4]):
            message_display("NEW RECORD!", 2, 2)
            del Scoreboard[-1]
            Scoreboard.append(name+ str(b))
            Scoreboard.sort(reversed=True)
```

EDIT: Just to be clear, Scoreboard is a list and it's contents are from a json file

Comment: Is "Scoreboard" a pygame class?

Comment: @HugoCornel It is a list that is opened from a file at the start of the program

Comment: Would it make sense to store each element of ScoreBoard as a tuple like (name, time) ? That way you can sort on solely the time.

Comment: @sir_snoopalot could you give me an example of that code please? I'm really new

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could make each element in the scoreboard list into a nested tuple in the list- I don't know what file type you're using, but I expect you could save it in this format. If it was a list of nested tuples, you could sort it using the [sorted] method. The [key] parameter will allow you to sort based on the index position 1 instead of 0, and the [reverse] parameter will allow it to sort in descending order.

```
data = sorted(data, reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
```